# Partition of unity (Husemoller definition)

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles

I'm currently studying bundles from Husemoller ["Fibre Bundles"](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/husemoller) and I'd like to understand the definition of partition of unity given in the book :

I think for the first time there's a reference (Theorem $4.3$,p.$29$) where the author says

"Let $(\eta_i)_{i \in I}$ be an envelope of unity subordinate to the open covering $(U_i)_{i \in I}$, that is, the support of $\eta_i \subset U_i$ and $\max_{i \in I}\eta_i(b) = 1$".

I think this is a slightly different notion of partition of unity given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) and I'd like to understand in this context if the latter follows from having a Partition_of_unity. For example the "envelope" doesn't seem to ask the condition on the closure on the support.

Morover, p.$31$ Proposition $5.4$ Husemoller takes a partition of unity $(\eta_i)_{i \in I}$ using only paracompactness of $B$. This seems in contradiction with p.$50$ where "It is a standard result that a Hausdorff space $B$ is paracompact if and only if each open covering is numerable". My question here is : In Proposition $5.4$ there are some properties on the space (i.e. $B$ Hausdorff) in order to have a partition of unity?

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit :** In particular I'd like to whether there's a proof of the existence of an "envelope of unity subordinate to the open covering" and its dependance with the existance of a partition of unity and hyphotesis on the spaces.

Comment: For a partition of unity we need Hausdorff + paracompact and the result on p.50 is nonsense as it stands (almost any uncountable space has uncountable open covers..) How does Husemoller define "support"?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm probably wrong but I don't think he defines the support with a pointed definition.

Comment: What do you mean a "pointed definition"? It's just a subset of the domain, normally $\overline{\{x\mid f(x) \neq 0\}}$ for a function $f: X \to \Bbb R$.

Comment: I meant that there's no formal description for it, as for example "definition 1.1" for bundles. I'm aware that the one you wrote (although sometimes the closure of the set is not required), but since Husemoller uses a lot of different terms from my terminology, I thought that my questions could have been answered simply by "is using just another word for the same thing". Unfortunately this doesn't seem the case.

Comment: The line with two origins is a non-Hausdorf space in which each open covering has a locally-finite open refinement, but not necessarily a subordinate partition of unity. Because of such examples many authors require a separation condition in their definition of paracompactness ($T_1$ is sufficient). While Husemoller does not seem to make any explicit stipulation, it may be wise to add one in yourself while quoting his statements.